# I’m getting on a plane! I need my iPad to charge… it’s stuck at 80%. Is it optimizing? If so, how do I force a full charge?

Tags: ipad, battery, charging, ipados

I’ve tried everything to get it to charge past 80%… different charger bricks and cables, restarted, low power mode… won’t go past 80%.

Unlike iPhone, there doesn’t seem to be an obvious way to force a full charge. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To get maximum charge in most circumstances, connect it to a charger. Once you see it charging, keep it connected and power off the device.

> Settings  > General > Shut Down, then drag the slider

https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/turn-ipad-off-or-on-ipad63d30b5a/ipados

If it doesn’t go past 80% you will need to do things that take longer than waiting to board a flight like restoring the device or seeking hardware repair. This will ensure that no stuck process or download is draining the battery while it attempts to negotiate the best charge current from the adapter and cable you have connected.